# get components by string names in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-component

I have a component that has some other components imported in for example:

```
import ComponentA from './components/ComponentA.js';
import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB.js';
import ComponentC from './components/ComponentC.js';
class Main extends Component {
...
```

then I have a function inside the main component named `returnChild(String childName)` that gets a string input, for example `ComponentA` or `ComponentB`, and returns the Component Object.

now I'm using a switch case to do it but components are too many and my source is messy. is there any way to get the value by string name in reactJS? For example:

```
returnChild = (childName) => {
    return get_value_by_name(childName)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need the string? Add in ur `Main` code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a config of components and then return the component based on config. e.g.,

```
import ComponentA from './components/ComponentA.js';
import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB.js';
import ComponentC from './components/ComponentC.js';
....

const STRING_TO_COMPONENTS = {
    'componentA': componentA,  //the key is a string and value is a component object
    'componentB': componentB,  
    'componentC': componentC,  
    ....
}
```

and while using, you can use it something like this

```
returnChild = childName => STRING_TO_COMPONENTS[childName];
```

That would be the neatest method I know.

Comment: no. I dont want to duplicate the names. I want to make it dynamic

Comment: That is dynamic and you're not creating duplicate names. You're just making an object which "dynamically" will give you the component. Also, please comment the solution if you find anything better.

Comment: I didn't found any good solution. for "dynamically" I meant when a new component is added to components directory. I don't have to its name serveral times

Comment: Because there isn't any better solution. If there were, someone would've answered your question :)